# Mostrar los eventos en fullcalendar por medio de JSON

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

Estoy apenas aprendiendo a usar el fullCalendar de bootstrap y después de estar buscando la solución no pude encontrarla, mi código es el siguiente:

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, 
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, 
      events: {
        url: 'getEventos/',
        error: function() {
          alert(1);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**controlador**

```
public function getEventos(){
    $eventos = Eventooooo::find(1);
    $evento = ['title' => $eventos->evento,
               'start' => $eventos->fechaEvento,
               'end'   => $eventos->fechaEvento,
    ];
    return response()->json($evento);
}
```

Estoy mandando un JSON con los index de la manera que espera recibirlo calendar para así solo mandar el response a 'event', y efectivamente, como respuesta me esta trayendo los datos que necesito. Con este código que estoy usando, no me muestra ningún error pero tampoco me muestra el evento dentro del calendario, estuve siguiendo un tutorial donde la persona tampoco le mostraba el dato entonces tuvo que hacer lo siguiente:

**código tutorial**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $.get('getEventos/', function(response, state){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: $.parseJSON(response),
    });
  });
```

});

Pero eso a mi me genera un error y no me funciono. Quisiera saber si alguien a tenido este mismo problema y como solucionarlo, gracias.

Comment: Debido a que nunca he intentado cargar desde ajax los eventos no se si el problema sea que en `events` te hace falta encerrar con `[...]`, o bien, dado que estas usando un recurso externo en vez de usar `events` tienes que usar `eventSources`

Comment: @JuankGlezz muchas gracias por responder, ya lo intente de la manera que me dices tu, lo intente ya de varias maneras y sigo sin poder, al momento de hacerlo como el código del tutorial me sale este error ´VM2863:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1´, ¿alguna idea sobre eso?

Comment: Es posible que no estés recibiendo un objeto JSON valido, una posible solución a ese error es usar `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: pruba fornato de fecha yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar usando algo como los siguientes ejemplos, ya que podría ser algo relacionado al dataType esperado

```
$.get('getEventos/', function(response, state){
    // lógica
}, 'json');
```

o también con:

```
$.getJSON('getEventos/', function(response, state){
    // lógica
});
```